# Using DataView with nodejs Buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to read/write some binary data using the [DataView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) object. It seems to work correctly when the buffer is initialized from a `UInt8Array`, however it if pass it a nodejs `Buffer` object the results seem to be off. Am I using the API incorrectly?

```
    import { expect } from 'chai';

    describe('read binary data', () => {

      it('test buffer', () => {
        let arr = Buffer.from([0x55,0xaa,0x55,0xaa,0x60,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xd4,0x03,0x00,0x00,0x1c,0xd0,0xbb,0xd3,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00])
        let read = new DataView(arr.buffer).getUint32(0, false);
        expect(read).to.eq(0x55aa55aa);
      })

      it('test uint8array', () => {
        let arr = new Uint8Array([0x55,0xaa,0x55,0xaa,0x60,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xd4,0x03,0x00,0x00,0x1c,0xd0,0xbb,0xd3,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00])
        let read = new DataView(arr.buffer).getUint32(0, false);
        expect(read).to.eq(0x55aa55aa);
      })

    })
```

The one with the buffer fails with

```
AssertionError: expected 1768779887 to equal 1437226410
      + expected - actual

      -1768779887
      +1437226410
```

Answer (score 2):

Nodejs `Buffer` is just a view over underlying allocated buffer that can be a lot larger. This is how to get `ArrayBuffer` out of Buffer:

```
function getArrayBufferFromBuffer( buffer ) {
  return buffer.buffer.slice( buffer.byteOffset, buffer.byteOffset + buffer.byteLength ) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try use this [buf.copy](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_copy_target_targetstart_sourcestart_sourceend)

```js
const buf = fs.readFileSync(`...`);
const uint8arr = new Uint8Array(buf.byteLength);

buf.copy(uint8arr, 0, 0, buf.byteLength);
const v = new DataView(uint8arr.buffer);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

This helped (not sure if this is the most elegant):

```
const buff = Buffer.from(msgBody, 'base64');
let uint8Array = new Uint8Array(buff.length);
for(let counter=0;counter<buff.length;counter++) {
    uint8Array[counter] = buff[counter];
    //console.debug(`uint8Array[${counter}]=${uint8Array[counter]}`);
}
let dataview = new DataView(uint8Array.buffer, 0, uint8Array.length);
```